# Error while installing ibm case manager 5.2.1 on windows server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, filenet-p8, ibm-case-manager

I’m using cmpit 5.2.1 on windows server 2012 to install ibm case manager 5.2.1, I’m having an error in step 34/38 in the installation.
In cpit_install_stdout:

```html
Install-InvokeDescription: (34/38) configNexus.bat
invokeScript: C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\cmpit\install-scripts\configNexus.bat

Cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\cmpit\install-scripts\configNexus.bat" "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\cmpit\install-scripts" "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\cmpit\decompressed" "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\IbmSoft" 64 "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\cmpit"

OUTPUT>====================
OUTPUT>Start configNexus.bat
OUTPUT>19:06
OUTPUT>setdirs running
OUTPUT>Start setdirs.bat
OUTPUT>"C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\ECMClient\configure"
OUTPUT>Démarrage de l'exécution de toutes les tâches dans le profil NexusConfig.
OUTPUT>
OUTPUT>Update the FileNet P8 Client Connector Files *****
OUTPUT>
OUTPUT>Configure the Connection to Your LDAP Server 
OUTPUT>Une erreur s'est produite lors de l'exécution de la tâche Configure the Connection to Your LDAP Server.
OUTPUT>L'exécution de la tâche a échoué avec les messages suivants :
OUTPUT>
OUTPUT>La configuration de l'authentification LDAP a échoué.La connexion au serveur LDAP a été établie.
OUTPUT>
OUTPUT>Pour obtenir des informations de connexion supplémentaires, voir le fichier journal :
OUTPUT>C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\ECMClient\logs\nexus_configmgr_workspace\.metadata\.log
OUTPUT>Begin sleeping
ERROR>The system cannot find the path specified.
OUTPUT>End sleeping
OUTPUT>ERROR - configurejdbcecm.ok not found. configNexus failed.  Refer to "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\cmpit\install-scripts\profiles\NexusConfig\status" for more details.
Process completed with exit code: -1
ERROR in InvokeScripts-function - Terminate the remaining scripts.
***Aborting InvokeScripts-Install function.
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not read French, but Google Translate suggests that your LDAP configuration isn't properly configured.

If you look at the log you might get some more information:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\ECMClient\logs\nexus_configmgr_workspace\.metadata\.log`

The other error suggests that a file is missing:
`The system cannot find the path specified.
ERROR - configurejdbcecm.ok not found.
Refer to "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\cmpit\install-scripts\profiles\NexusConfig\status"`

You should fix the LDAP error before fixing the 'configurejdbcecm.ok' error; 'configurejdbcecm.ok' might be missing as a result of the LDAP problem.